# Cantor function behavior close to point $1$

Tags: real-analysis, singular-measures

I was reading about the Cantor function (The Devil's Staircase) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) and based on the picture and the description of the function, it seems to me that when $x \rightarrow 1$, 
$$1-c(x)=o(1-x).$$

Is it true? Is in this case the rate of $1-c(x)$ going to $0$ as $x \rightarrow 1$ well defined?

Comment: $1 - c(x) = c(1-x)$. Is $c(y)\in o(y)$ for $y \to 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your o-notation. But I guess that you are interested in the left-sided derivative at the point 1 -- it is infinite. Described by limits:
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1-c(x)}{1-x} = \infty.$$

From now on, I will focus on the behavior at the point 0 -- it is more handy and the Cantor function is symmetric by point [0.5, 0.5].

Take the two sequences $a_n = 3^{-n}$, $b_n = 2\cdot3^{-n}$ approaching to zero. They converges to zero and they have the same values in the Cantor function: $c(a_n) = c(b_n) = 2^{-n}$. We can describe the behavior of $c$ on the sequence $a_n$ by function $f(x)=x^{\log_3(2)}$ and on the sequence $b_n$ by function $g(x) = (\frac x2)^{\log_3(2)} = 2^{-\log_3(2)}\cdot f(x)$.

These functions are actually bounds for the Cantor function, given that we can say that $c\asymp x^{\log_3(2)}$, using the [asymptotic notation 6.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AsymptoticNotation.html).

I could prove the fact that $f,g$ are the bounds, but it is rather technical, so I hope it won't be necessary :-)